# trying to write a correct regex, help please

Tags: java, regex

here's a little regex i wrote:

```
\\b(?!N|O)(?!Y{1}|N{1}).+_
```

this regex is supposed to match any sequence of characters that start with a new line or a white space (therefore \b) not including the word NOT and the characters Y or N at the beinning

((?!N|O)(?!Y{1}|N{1})) and ends with an underline (hence _).

my problem is that i want it to be reluctant (i think that's the right term). meaning:
in the next text:

```
FILE_sldkf aTEMP_sdlkf
```

it would match FILE and aTEMP differently, right now i get

```
FILE_sldkf aTEMP_
```

together as one match. any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Consider accepting some answers once in a while, see: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sometimes a good idea to check the exceptions separately and not pack everything in one single regex.

Therefore I would do something like this (pseudocode):

```
if (string matches "\\b(\\w+_)") then
    matched = extract matched part for () group 1
    if (matched not matches "^(N|Y|NOT)") then  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like:

\b[^NY].*?_

Which means: Word boundary (\b - double escaped like your code), followed by a character other than N or Y ([^NY] - that includes the word NOT) followed by any character (.) 0 or more times (*) greedily (? - not reluctant) followed by underscore (_)

Comment: Or to keep as close to the same as your original regex if it is working for you just add the greedy question mark before the underscore like this: \\b(?!N|O)(?!Y{1}|N{1}).+?_

Comment: hi i tried both but now it finds nothing. here's the text i tried it on: FILE_A*B*C

Comment: Do you have the right number of backslashes before the b at the beginning. I tested the first regex (using javascript - but I am pretty sure the syntax is the same) it on 'FILE_A*B*C' and it matches 'FILE_'. And tested on 'FILE_A*B*C FILE_X*Y*Z' and it still matched 'FILE_'.

Answer (score 0):

`\b[^NY\s](?!\w*NOT\w*)\w+?_`  , I suppose this is the regex that you are looking for.. You should put one more escape characters for java..

Sample  ;

FILE_sldkf_ aTEMP_sdlkf NOT_ NER_FG YER_ 343_4434_ FileNOT_ fil_

Matches :

FILE_ aTEMP 343_ fil_